# How do I execute a function only once in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, functional-programming, combinators

I want to make a CoffeeScript function that even if it is invoked multiple times, has its effects only run once.

Is one of these, or another way a good way to make a once-invokable function ? Is the extra `do` an issue or actually better ?

```
once_maker_a = (f)-> 
  done=false
  ->
    f.call() unless done
    done=true

once_maker_b = (f)->
  do(done=false)-> 
    -> 
      f.call() unless done
      done=true

oa = once_maker_a(-> console.log 'yay A')
ob = once_maker_b(-> console.log 'yay B')

oa()
yay A      #runs the function passed to the once_maker
undefined  #return value of console.log
oa()
undefined  #look, does not reprint 'yay A'

ob()
yay B
undefined
ob()
undefined
```

I know about http://api.jquery.com/one/ and http://underscorejs.org/#once but in this case using those libraries is not an option.

Comment: The [Underscore implementation](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.6.0/underscore.js#L749) is pretty close to your `once_maker_a` except you're not handling `f`'s return value.

Comment: The only things that are missing here is handling of arguments that are passed to the original function and the return value. Besides that, you have a pretty reasonable implementation.

Comment: The original indentation issue is gone, but it was failing to indent under do(done=false)->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is one of these a good way to make a once-invokable function?

As @UncleLaz stated in the comments, you're ignoring any arguments to the function. Also you don't memoize the return value of the function, and always just return `true`. If you're really only caring about side effects, then that might not be a problem.

> Is the extra do an issue or actually better?

In your case it's an issue. [Check out the compiled javascript](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aonce_maker_b%20%3D%20%28f%29-%3E%0A%20%20do%28done%3Dfalse%29-%3E%20%0A%20%20-%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20f.call%28%29%20unless%20done%0A%20%20%20%20done%3Dtrue). Even if you [corrected the indentation](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aonce_maker_b%20%3D%20%28f%29-%3E%0A%20%20do%28done%3Dfalse%29-%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20-%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20f.call%28%29%20unless%20done%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20done%3Dtrue), it's not better since it's just unnecessarily introducing another scope.

A better, minimalistic way might be

```
once_maker = (f) ->
  -> 
    f?.apply this, arguments
    f = null
```

(still not caring about the return value)

Comment: Wow, yeah, the indentation thing sneaked by me. You're right about the extra scope, and the par for code golf just went down a notch with your elegant answer. Thanks :)

Comment: yes, for code golfing it's nice, but for really readable code I think the `f.apply this, arguments unless f == null` approach is better.